# A Generic Drag and Drop Handler for .net WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have an application that I inherited and would like to improve. One area that I can cut a lot of code is `Drag and Drop` handling. In that, the application handles drag and drop of same type of objects but the code for it repeated over (with slight variations) and a lot of event wiring code. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. The component (a `UserControl`) must have a way to declare (within the form) types of items  it supports dragging and/or dropping
2. The component must have a way to broadcast that it accepted a dragged item
3. Once the dragging starts, all the items (that can accept the item being dragged) should be notified that they dragging has started
4. The dragging could be started from a contained control (of the `UserControl`)

That way I can handle both moving and copying of objects within a common class and without decorating the host form with the same boilerplate code.

Is that possible to achieve in `WinForms`? Any code that already exists for that?

Comment: There's nothing in Winforms that will help you do this.  There's nothing in Winforms that stops you from doing this.